# parse data from JSON url using javascript

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, cors

I want to make an ajax request and parse the JSON response.
I have tried to do so with this code but with no luck

```
var url = 'http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser \
          /ResolveVanityURL/v0001/?key=private_key&vanityurl=zacktm'
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

The response that I get is:

```
{
"response": {
    "steamid": "76561198181548891",
    "success": 1
  }
}
```

the output I want: `76561198181548891`

Comment: If you check the browser's console I think you'll see an error about not being able to make a cross-domain Ajax request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A temporary solution for development would be to use [crossorigin.me](https://crossorigin.me/)

Code would be:

```
var url = 'http://crossorigin.me/http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/ResolveVanityURL/v0001/?key=0E385DC97C8423D8DD9CD11944187F38&vanityurl=zacktm'
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    alert(data.response.steamid);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I see CORS is enabled in your API.

A temporary solution would be to disable the CORS filter on your browser, but to get a permanent solution you will need to add the CORS headers on your backend REST API.

Once that is done you can try the following:

```
$.get('http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/ResolveVanityURL/v0001/?key=0E385DC97C8423D8DD9CD11944187F38&vanityurl=zacktm', function(data) {
   alert(data.response.steamid);   
});
```

`data.response.steamid` will give you the steamid

Comment: the alert didn't even run

Comment: @Amromtm Do you have JQuery added? And also can you please check you browser console when you try to run this?

Comment: I see CORS headers are present of your API. Make sure that CORS allows your API to access the json

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/ResolveVanityURL/v0001/?key=0E385DC97C8423D8DD9CD11944187F38&vanityurl=zacktm. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: @Amromtm Yes, that is what I was saying. A temporary solution would be to disable the CORS filter on your browser, but to get a permanent solution you will need to add the CORS headers on your backend REST API.

Comment: i've googled this .. and maybe another solution can work with JSONP
but really don't know what is "jsonp" and how to use

Comment: @Amromtm What are you using in the backend?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118719/discussion-between-pritam-banerjee-and-amromtm).

Answer (score 1):

1.

```
var url = 'https://itunes.apple.com/in/rss/topalbums/limit=10/json';
```

2.

```
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {

      alert(data.feed.entry[0]["im:name"].label);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = 'http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser \
          /ResolveVanityURL/v0001/?key=private_key&vanityurl=zacktm';
$.get(url, function(data){
    var reply = $.parseJSON(data);
    // Or plain JavaScript
    // var reply= JSON.parse(data);
    alert(reply.reponse.steamid);
});
```

Note that you cannot use XmlHttpRequest to external servers with localhost if server allow-origin: localhost is not set